# css height~min-height:100% not work

Tags: html, css

Here's the thing, the div not stretching fully to the rest of the page.
using the height/min-height:100%; thing but not working

below is the aspx page code

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="divHeader">
            <div class="divContainer">
            <div class="divContentLeft">
                <a href="Dashboard.aspx"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="divContentLeft">
                <div class="divContentRow"></div>
                <div class="divContentRow"></div>

                <div class="divContentRow">
                    <div class="divContentLeft">
                        <a href="Dashboard.aspx"><span>Some Title Here</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divContentRow">
                    <div class="divContentLeft">
                        <a href="#"><img src="../images/menu_icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" onclick="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="divBody">
            <div class="divContentLeft" style="min-height:100%; height:100%;">
                <div class="menu-bar">
                    <ul class="menu-bar-ul" runat="server" id="divMenuBar">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="divContentLeft">                    
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                    
                </div>

        </div>    
        <div class="divFooter">

        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css

```
body {  
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.divHeader a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:800;
}

.wrapper {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.divHeader, .divBody, .divFooter {
    padding:5px;
}

.divHeader {
    height:15%;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    background-color:#CFCFC4;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
}

.divBody {
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    min-height:80%;
    height:auto;
}

.divFooter {
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    clear:both;
}

.divContentLeft {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.divContainer {
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentRow {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}

.divContentDetail {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}


.ui-widget-header {
    background:#b39eb5;
}

.divContentTextbox {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentLabel {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.divMenuBarBlock {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.menu-bar {
    float:left;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #CFCFC4;
}

.menu-bar a{
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: .002em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:medium;
}

.menu-bar li{
    list-style:none;
}

.menu-bar ul li ul li:hover {
    background:gray;
}

.menu-bar-ul ul {
    display:none;
}

.no-sub:hover {
    background:gray;
}

.sub-arrow {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.menu-bar-ul li.click ul {
    display:block;
}

.menu-bar .sub-arrow:after {
    content:'\203A';
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-bar li.click .sub-arrow:after {
    content: '\2039';
}

.menu-bar-ul ul a:before {
    content:'\203A';
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

So, the main problem is how i stretch the freaking div to the rest of the remaining page?

Because my navigation menu bar stretch as long as the only displayed item there
also the content isn't stretched to the rest of the page

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try this html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: seems like the problem is the div body not wrapping it's children
since i cant get any highlighted area on firebug

Comment: divBody's child elements has no height...since its empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vh` units. `100vh` is 100% of the viewport height. This doesn't require setting the parents' heights and has [good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) - all browsers and ie >= 9.

```css
body {  
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.divHeader a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:800;
}

.wrapper {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}

.divHeader, .divBody, .divFooter {
    padding:5px;
}

.divHeader {
    height:15%;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    background-color:#CFCFC4;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
}

.divBody {
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    min-height:80%;
    height:auto;
}

.divFooter {
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    clear:both;
}

.divContentLeft {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.divContainer {
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentRow {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}

.divContentDetail {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}


.ui-widget-header {
    background:#b39eb5;
}

.divContentTextbox {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.divContentLabel {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.divMenuBarBlock {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.menu-bar {
    float:left;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #CFCFC4;
}

.menu-bar a{
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: .002em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:medium;
}

.menu-bar li{
    list-style:none;
}

.menu-bar ul li ul li:hover {
    background:gray;
}

.menu-bar-ul ul {
    display:none;
}

.no-sub:hover {
    background:gray;
}

.sub-arrow {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.menu-bar-ul li.click ul {
    display:block;
}

.menu-bar .sub-arrow:after {
    content:'\203A';
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-bar li.click .sub-arrow:after {
    content: '\2039';
}

.menu-bar-ul ul a:before {
    content:'\203A';
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="divHeader">
    <div class="divContainer">
      <div class="divContentLeft">
        <a href="Dashboard.aspx"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="divContentLeft">
        <div class="divContentRow"></div>
        <div class="divContentRow"></div>

        <div class="divContentRow">
          <div class="divContentLeft">
            <a href="Dashboard.aspx"><span>Some Title Here</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divContentRow">
          <div class="divContentLeft">
            <a href="#"><img src="../images/menu_icon.png" height="20px" width="20px" onclick="" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divBody">
    <div class="divContentLeft" style="min-height:100%; height:100%;">
      <div class="menu-bar">
        <ul class="menu-bar-ul" runat="server" id="divMenuBar">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divContentLeft">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="divFooter">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx dude, seems i must measurer the height/width with vh,
its working

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer you're welcome, `vh` and `vw` are great.

Answer (score -1):

`.divBody {
    height: 80%;
...
}`

is not being applied. I changed it to

`.divBody {
    height: 80% !important;
...`

and the wrapper div appeared to extend the entire height of the page. You could also figure out what is overriding the height attribute, if you're so inclined.

Chrome has a great DevTools. Just right-click a page in Chrome and hit inspect. As you mouse over items, their corresponding containers are highlighted. You can change a selectors css and see the change in real time.